# Beautiful Soup parsing amazon page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hi I'm trying to parse Amazon's page for book details so I'm using beautiful soup

link: [https://www.amazon.com/Dogs-Purpose-Novel-Humans/dp/0765326264/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1489776209&sr=1-1&keywords=books](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0765326264)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = raw_input("Enter a website to extract the URL's from: ")
r  = requests.get(url)

data = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")

#Grab book details
print soup.find("table", {"id": "productDetailsTable" })
```

But when I try this code I get None as a result, I'm sure the id productDetailsTable exist, and when I try running this code with dummy html it works just not with a url?

Comment: Any reason you wouldn't just use Amazon's API?

Comment: Was trying to get specific product details for other products that aren't really accessible in their API but shows up on their html page :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did not see productDetailsTable on https://www.amazon.com

I had to do https://www.amazon.com/ in order to receive the html data.

Here is my slightly modified Python 3 code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = input("Enter a website to extract the URL's from: ")
r  = requests.get(url)

data = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")

print(soup.text)
```

It prints the html for the page.

You'll notice that amazon is smart.  The html includes the Robot Check:

```
if (true === true) {
var ue_t0 = (+ new Date()),
    ue_csm = window,
    ue = { t0: ue_t0, d: function() { return (+new Date() - ue_t0); } },
    ue_furl = "fls-na.amazon.com",
    ue_mid = "ATVPDKIKX0DER",
    ue_sid = (document.cookie.match(/session-id=([0-9-]+)/) || [])[1],
    ue_sn = "opfcaptcha.amazon.com",
    ue_id = 'R8D7EEN5FVS7RWC2M549';
}
Enter the characters you see below
Sorry, we just need to make sure you're not a robot. For best results, please make sure your browser is accepting cookies.
```

It is keeping you from reading Amazon's page.  You'll have to do more, probably with [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) and include [headers](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/) and [cookie](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/_modules/requests/cookies/) information.

Comment: @Chad Crowe I am looking to solve the similar problem do you have a working example that we can test it on I am trying out multiple things but nothing is working in my case. Thanks

Comment: @ankushreddy, sorry, I do not.  It was a hobby project that I did not finish.

Comment: Need this too, and can't get it working someone has any idea how to get around this?